# jq command to add onto a map

Tags: json, scripting, terraform, append, jq

Is there a command to use jq to add onto this type of map?
append an array of maps using keys (ie, vm1, vm2, vm3)

Note: I have an existing vm_map {} in a json file and i want to add to the vm_map

this is my new_json.json file

```
{
  "gcs_config": [
    {
      "bucket_name": "somebucket",
      "bucket_readers": [],
      "bucket_writers": []
    }
  ],
  "label_application": "someapp",
  "label_environment": "dev",
  "lits_vm_zone": "somezone",
  "project_id": "someproject",
  "region": "someregion",
  "storage_bucket_required": true,
  "vm_map" : {}
}
```

expected: using jq to add onto vm_maps map. I will have an empty vm_map and each time it runs, i will add a x amount of new entries.

```
{
  "gcs_config": [
    {
      "bucket_name": "somebucket",
      "bucket_readers": [],
      "bucket_writers": []
    }
  ],
  "label_application": "someapp",
  "label_environment": "dev",
  "lits_vm_zone": "zone-a",
  "project_id": "someproject",
  "region": "someregion",
  "storage_bucket_required": true,
    "vm_map": {
    "vm1": {
      "host": "vm1",
      "network": "10.1.1.1",
      "name": "vm1"
    },
    "vm2": {
      "host": "123",
      "network": "10.1.12",
      "name": "vm2"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this is actually HCL for terraform for tfvars or variables.tf

Comment: If you want to generate variable files, use `terraform.tfvars.json` instead as `json` is more standardized and easier to generate. Edit: Also that's a map, not a list.

Comment: yes, you are right, i should call that a map. thanks!

Comment: You didn't provide sufficient information. You said you want a number of additional entries to be added, but you didn't say how many, and you didn't say what to use for the host, name and network of those new entries. We can't possibly answer your question if you provide virtually no information!

Comment: Hi ikegami. I will have a loop that will add x amount of times. The vm_map will be empty and each time I run a script it will populate the variable. I want example like vm3:[{host: vm3, ipaddress: 10.10.10.11, name: num3vm}] . I just want one command to add a new entry and I will create a loop

Comment: Re "*I will have a loop that will add x amount of times.*", So the program should only add one instead of x, in contradiction to what you previously said?  And still haven't provided any of the necessary info. "I have a loop" tell us where `vm3` and `10.10.10.11`, `num3vm` come from. Are they params passed to `jq` using `--arg`?

Comment: (You need to tag `@ikegami` to get it to notify me)

Comment: @ikegami, I will have run bash script which contains $VMHOST, $VM_NAME, $VMHOST, $NETWORK_IP) which i want to pass through into the jq command. yes

Comment: $VMHOST will also be the key of the map like $VMHOST:[{host: $VM_NAME, $NETWORK_IP: 10.10.10.11, name: VM_NAME}]

Answer (score 2):

The file you describe is not valid JSON. I'm assuming you mean

```json
{
  "vm_map": {
    "vm1": {
      "host": "vm1",
      "network": "xxxxx",
      "name": "xxxxxxx"
    },
    "vm2": {
      "host": "vm2",
      "network": "xxxxx",
      "name": "xxxxxxx"
    }
  }
}
```

You can use this:

```bash
jq \
   --arg VMHOST     "$VMHOST"     \
   --arg NETWORK_IP "$NETWORK_IP" \
   --arg VM_NAME    "$VM_NAME"    \
'
   .vm_map[ $VMHOST ] = {
      host:    $VMHOST,
      network: $NETWORK_IP,
      name:    $VM_NAME
   }
'
```

Comment: i think the command is fine in a way but somehow it needs to append. if i were to loop through ,it only replaces one entry. how can it keep appending to the existing file and map var

Comment: The command *is* fine. The problem is entirely with the file you pass to it

Comment: And you're completely wrong. It doesn't replace any entries. It always adds (appends) one.

Comment: Re "*i think the command is fine*", It is. The problem is entirely with the file you pass to it. /// Re "*somehow it needs to append*". It already does. /// Re "*it only replaces one entry*", No, it doesn't replace any entries.  It appends one. /// Re "*how can it keep appending to the existing file*", Again, you need to save the changes to `new_json.json`

Comment: that means, you have to append and save to a new file each time there is a new entry right?
jq \
   --arg VMHOST     "22aa3"     \
   --arg NETWORK_IP "asddasds" \
   --arg VM_NAME    "VM_NAME"    \
'
   .vm_map[ $VMHOST ] = {
      host:    $VMHOST,
      network: $NETWORK_IP,
      name:    $VM_NAME
   }
   
' tmp/a.json > tmp/b.json 

and do the same to b.json and so on - @ikegami

Comment: Nothing stops you from copying b.json over a.json

Comment: I got it working i want by adding the following to the end. At the beginning, add  tmpfile=$(mktemp) ,  cp new_json.json "$tmpfile" and at the end i added a mktemp file
 > new_json.json && rm -f "$tmpfile"

Do you know the command to remove eveything inside vm_map? 
i am thinking of deleting everything inside vm_map at the end of the script